# Stability of Runge Kutta methods

Tags: numerical-methods, stability-in-odes, runge-kutta-methods

For the stability of RK methods, $y' = ky$ test function is used. What does this stability imply for general $f(t, y(t))$? What is useful meaning of stability and stability region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most constructs, like machines of robots, while having many moving parts, will have a very restricted overall motion repertoire. Meaning that apart from small deviations due to the inherent flexibility of parts, the whole construct will move inside a low-dimensional sub-manifold of the full state space.

Translated into ODE this means that many interesting systems, while having a high-dimensional state space, will rapidly converge toward some equilibrium  moving along a low-dimensional manifold.

A numerical method should preserve this qualitative behavior. The common definitions of stability codify this for linear systems, with the expectations that non-linear systems can be locally linearized and that the error of the linearization is small enough over at least one step so that the linear stability also transfers to the non-linear system. When this fails, the combination of method and ODE is called "stiff". (Usually, a problem is stiff for all explicit methods if at all.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you, please, clarify these two points. What is the point of your second paragraph. I.e, how low dimensionality is related to this problem? And what is the relation between stability of system itself and the numerical solution?

Comment: I reproduced an example of Hairer/Wanner in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3183582/115115. There you can see how a slowly moving equilibrium is surrounded by a fast flow towards it. But as numerical methods are applied, the trapezoidal method, despite having one order more and in principle being stable as well, does not perform as well as the implicit Euler method. In a simulation, the better stability of the Euler method will be more faithful to the qualitative behavior.

Comment: This effective reduction of the dimension of the system from 2 $(x,y)$ to one via $y\approx\cos(x)$ can be more radical if the dimension of the system is higher. Another example is the approximation of DAE systems by nearly singular ODE. That is, $\dot x=f(x,y),~0=g(x,y)$ is replaced by $\dot x=f(x,y),~\epsilon\dot y=g(x,y)$ with some $\epsilon\approx 0$. If $g$ is sensibly chosen or modified, the flow will rapidly move towards the manifold $0=g(x,y)$, effectively reducing the dimension to that of $x$.

Comment: I heard that if some states of the system converge much faster than the others then the system is stiff. You also mention something like this, I guess. But could you please little bit conceptually explain why this happens and how can this be predicted using y' = ky function.

Comment: Yes, it is a balancing act, as the step size is the same for the fast and slow components. In the fast component, the absolute error will quickly become negligible, while the relative error is scale invariant. Ideally, you would have a small step size until the fast component is in equilibrium, then large step sizes accounting for the slow component. However, the stability, if and how much the numerical method overshoots the equilibrium, is more dependent on the relative error. This is dominantly a problem for explicit methods, implicit methods tend to undershoot.

Comment: So, to conclude, you mean that nonlinear system will behave like a linear system near the equilibrium and hence stability for y' = ky would hopefully mean stability of the method for nonlinear system around equilibrium, right?

Comment: And by "many interesting systems" in your answer, you mean stiff ones, right?

Comment: Yes, for the discussion of stability only stiff problems are interesting, for non-stiff problems the approximation order of the method has the dominating interest.

Comment: Thank you very much.