# Picking a numerical methods for solving stiff ODE systems with fixed time step.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory, linear-approximation

I am currently studying analytical and numerical methods and can't wrap my head around which methods to choose from.
The methods that I have learned so far are:

1. Forward Euler
2. Backward Euler
3. Modified Euler
4. Trapezoidal method
5. Runk Katta schemes

If we were given an ODE system, which methods would I choose to obtain the most accurate solution with a fixed $∆t$?

Comment: 1.-4. are educational methods. If you are to code the method yourself, and are to get useful results, use RK4 or the 3/8 method. Notice that nothing prevents you from doing $M$ steps with size $Δt/M$ and only record the last result. /// Better use a method from an established library that is verified and tested. Set the error tolerances appropriate to your system or modify your system so that uniform error tolerances can be applied.

Comment: @LutzLehmann what if we were restricted to only educational methods (1-4) to test our knowledge? Which one would I choose to use and why?

Comment: From a stability point-of-view, the implicit Euler method will work best, giving qualitatively useful results for larger step sizes than the second order methods. Of course, when you get to smaller step sizes as required by some sensible accuracy targets, the second order methods will work better than the first order methods. So try them both. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183453/pedagogical-example

Comment: @LutzLehmann I understand the Modified Euler is a form of predictor-corrector method and second-order accurate (similar to RK2), yet is unconditionally stable compare to the Trapezoidal method. Does the stability of the method play a factor when deciding between trapezoidal and modified euler?

Comment: The (A-)stability of the implicit trapezoidal and implicit midpoint methods is the same. If you consider the stability function, you get that $R(x+0i)\to -1$ for $x\to -\infty$, while imp. Euler has that limit going to $0$, thus being qualitatively little more correct, as demonstrated with the example. I'm not sure if that can be repaired with some other 2nd order method, what can be said is that $R(z)$ would have to be the [0/2] or [1/2] Padé approximation of $e^z$.