# Stiff ODEs: trouble detecting stiffness from the plot of an ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am reading through the very good Leveque book on numerical methods for ordinary and partial differential equations. In chapter 8 he shows a simple equation that is "stiff" in the ODE sense of the word.

$$
u' = \lambda(u - \cos{t}) - \sin{t}
$$

The solution is:

$$
u(t) = e^{\lambda(t - t_0)}(\eta - cos(t_0)) + \cos{t}
$$

So the ratio between $\lambda$ and the $\sin{t}$ will define the stiffness of the equation. That all makes sense. However, when I looked at the plot for this equation I could not understand what made it stiff? I always attribute stiffness with a lot of different time scales happening or a mixture of fast and slow frequencies. But the plot seems rather smooth, so why would the trapezoid rule have so much difficulty finding the solution?

That is my real question, based upon the plot below, what is making the solving stiff and causing the trapezoid method to bounce around to much--given that the curve is pretty smooth.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\sin(t)$ term acts like a driving force with frequency $1$. So indeed there are two time scales: one with speed $1$ (the driving force) and one with speed $\lambda$ (the part $u' = \lambda u$). If you want, you may augment the system with auxiliary equation $t' = 1$ to make it an autonomous system.

Another way to see the stiffness is to look at the stream lines. The way they turn almost at a right angle also indicates stiffness. The figure below plots streamlines of the field $(1, \lambda(u - \cos t) - \sin t)$

[image]

You can't tell that the problem is stiff by just looking at the solution (since it is always driven by slow processes away from the transition region), instead you need to inspect how rough is the trajectory field in the *neighbourhood* of the solution.

PS. I tried to reproduce the oscillation pattern of the trapezoidal method and I'm pretty sure that the solution plot and the numerical trajectory are obtained with different values of $\lambda$ ($\lambda \approx -5000$ for the method and $\lambda \sim -100$ for the solution). Below is the plot for $\Delta t = 0.2, \lambda = -30$ just to see how the trapezoidal method bounces in the ODE field.

[image]

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183453/pedagogical-example-of-nonlinear-ode for other plots with different parameters taken from the Hairer book.

Comment: @uranix Oh thanks so much for this answer. Yes, this makes sense. So it is about how quickly the trajectory field changes in the neighborhood of the solution. That makes a lot more sense. I kept thinking about solutions once I am on the curve, but in this example it is about the approach to the solution. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

What this kind of plot comparison shows is that for the stability function $R(z)$ one has

- $R(\infty)=0$ for the implicit Euler method with $R(z)=\dfrac1{1-z}$ and
- $R(\infty)=-1$ for the implicit trapezoidal method with $R(z)=\dfrac{2+z}{2-z}$.

The consequence is that in the impl. trap. method when $z=\lambda h$ is very large, the fast component of the solution will oscillate around the slowly moving equilibrium curve, while impl. Euler converges fast towards the equilibrium. The influence of the order on the error is usually observed only for smaller step sizes, for $|z|<3$ or so (see $R(-2)=0$ for the trapezoidal method).

Comment: this is very helpful. Interesting to see the difference between the two solver methods. Say, just a follow up question. So in the plots in the original post, the stiffness occurs as the point approaches the solution curve along the direction field or trajectory field. But I thought that there can also be stiffness once the point is on the actual solution curve too right? Is my statement or correct, or is stiffness only about the transient getting to the actual solution?

Comment: The oscillation around the equilibrium continues indefinitely, only the amplitude decreases exponentially. Stiffness is about forcing the step size to the boundary of the stability region when controlling the step size for a desired error level. This mostly happens for adaptive step-size control and explicit methods. The trapezoidal method does not strictly possess such a boundary, but as you see, useful stability is "softly" bounded.

Comment: The trapezoidal method is a boundary case that got its own dedication in the relevant section on L-stability of Hairer's book: *"The trapezoidal rule for the numerical integration of first-order ordinary differential equations is shown to possess, for a certain type of problem, an undesirable property. (A.R. Gourlay 1970)"*