# Stiff system of ODEs with known exact solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

Stiff systems of ODEs such as the [van der Pol oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator) and Robertson's chemical reaction do not have exact solutions (as far as I know).

Are there stiff systems of ODEs with known exact solutions, perhaps other than simple systems such as $y' = Ay$, where $A$ is some diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements vary significantly?

Comment: A still simple example is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217585/stiff-odes-trouble-detecting-stiffness. Generally one can add a forcing term to any given equation that makes a known function into a solution, this is also called MMS, method of manufactured solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Using the wonderful notes "STUDENT VERSION, Stiff Differential Equations" by
Kurt Bryan

**Example 1**

As you noted, the simplest example is to just create a diagonal system

$$y_1(t) = \lambda_1 y_1(t) \\ y_2(t) = λ_2 y_2(t)$$

The exact solution is given by

$$y_1(t) = y_1(0)e^{\lambda_1 t}, y_2(t) = y_2(0)e^{\lambda_2 t}$$

by choosing $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 <0$, for example $\lambda_1 = -1, \lambda_2 = -100$, we get stiff behavior.

**Example 2**

Can we find a constant matrix with the same eigenvalues as the previous problem? Yes, choose

$$y' = A y = \begin{bmatrix} -56 & 55 \\ 44 & -45 \end{bmatrix}$$

The exact solution is given by

$$y(t) = c_1 e^{-t} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + c_2 e^{-100t} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -0.8 \end{bmatrix}$$

**Example 3**

From the amazing book "Numerical Methods for Ordinary Differential Equations" by J. C. Butcher, a mildly stiff system is given by

$$\begin{align} y_1'(x) &= −16y_1 + 12y_2 + 16 \cos(x) − 13 \sin(x), y_1(0) = 1 \\
y_2'(x) &= 12y_1 − 9y_2 − 11 \cos(x) + 9 \sin(x), y_2(0) = 0 \end{align}$$

The exact solution is

$$y_1(x) = \cos(x), y_2(x) = \sin(x)$$

**Example 4**

You can find more examples of stiff systems with closed-form solutions at [*link*](http://acmbulletin.fiit.stuba.sk/vol4num3/satek.pdf), including an RC-circuit (for a real system using an electric circuit).

There are many [*solvers*](https://www.swmath.org/?term=stiff%20ODE%20equations&sortby=-rank&&page=1) for stiff systems.